# Can Netbean edit remote files

Tags: netbeans, file

If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25824410/470749 (and here is a video of Netbeans editing remote files: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKDJ5KAJoSg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans 6.9 for PHP, go to File->Project Properties.
In 'Categories', choose 'Run Configuration'. There's a bunch of options to get your whole project running on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is an option when you create project - Create project from files on remote server.